# after using system events my wpf application runs from some save state

Tags: c#, wpf, events

*I use SystemEvent.timecahnged in my wpf application.After execute the program my application save that state and alway runs from that.I changed many things in my code but it always run from the same state.*
the code i use for SystemEvent.TimeChanged is :

```
private void StartListening()
{
    Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.TimeChanged += new EventHandler(TimeHandler);
}

private void StopListening()
{
    Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.TimeChanged -= new  EventHandler(TimeHandler);
}

private void TimeHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
    String activity = "Time is Changed";
    String datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
    String[] list = datetime.Split(' ');
    String date = list[0].ToString();
    String time = list[1].ToString();
    da.addActivity(activity, date, time);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean build you Project and run again hopefully it will work

Comment: Always here for help!